# #android How to make multiple checkboxes' state changes in Baseadapter with a simple click on one checkbox?

Tags: android

I met a problem when building checkbox in listview using BaseAdapter.
I did find the method to change one checkbox at a time using the following link's code: http://lalit3686.blogspot.tw/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

However,I can't figure out how to make multiple checkboxes to change their states in BaseAdapter with a simple click on one of it,because I would find some checkboxes turn to wrong states again sometimes when I scroll.

[This is what I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICcjM.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
public class NewSongAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements Filterable{


Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
static List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
static List<Model> listFiltered = new ArrayList<Model>();
static NewSongAdapter newsongadp;

CustomFilter3 filter;
static Holder holder;
static boolean fromclick;
static int posi;

public NewSongAdapter(Context context,  List<Model> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = list;
    this.listFiltered=list;

    newsongadp=this;

}





@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listFiltered.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return listFiltered.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;

    Holder holder;
    posi = pos;
    int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("btn_check_holo_light", "drawable", "android");

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    if (convertView == null) {
        v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.newsongadp_view, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nstext);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.nscheckBox);
        holder.image=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.nsimageView);
        holder.checkBox.setButtonDrawable(id);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  

                int posi=getPosition;



                listFiltered.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                  if(listFiltered.get(posi).isDirect()==true)
                  { 
                      posi++;
                      while (posi < listFiltered.size() && listFiltered.get(posi).isDirect() != true) {

                              listFiltered.get(posi).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                              posi++;
                          }

                  }


                NewSongActivity.newsongadp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        v.setTag(holder);
        v.setTag(R.id.nstext, holder.text);
        v.setTag(R.id.nscheckBox, holder.checkBox);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
        holder = (Holder) v.getTag();


    }


    holder.checkBox.setTag(pos);
    holder.text.setTag(pos);


    holder.text.setText(listFiltered.get(pos).getName());

        if (listFiltered.get(pos).isSelected() == true) {


            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 191, 255));

        } else {


            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));


        }




        if(listFiltered.get(pos).isDirect() == true) {
        holder.text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder_fig);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    return v;
}





class Holder {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView text;
    ImageView image;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if(filter==null)
        filter=new CustomFilter3(listFiltered,this);


    return filter;
}
```

}

**Edit:**
Model.class:

```
public class Model {

private String name;
private boolean selected=false;
private boolean direct=false;


public Model(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Model(String name, Boolean direct)
{ this.name=name;
  this.direct=direct;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public boolean isDirect(){return direct; }

public void setIs_direct(boolean direct){
    this.direct = direct;
}
```

}

Comment: you should hold the state of the checkboxes.. for that you should maintain a boolean variable to check true or not

Comment: I did hold the state.That's what I am doing in OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: I do not mention Model class in the code,but it is similar to the link's code.

Comment: write that notifyDataSetChanged() above line of if condition

Comment: Nope.It still gets changing states while scrolling.

Comment: can you paste your model class here?

Comment: in place of setSelected while setting the value use true or false. and if true then let the item's checkbox be checked. if false then uncheck.don't forget to call notifydatassetchanged after setting the value to true or false

Comment: @RushiAyyappa I have added Model class now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Model
    {
  String text;
   boolean isChecked=false;

 Model(String text,boolean isChecked)
  {
   this.text=text;
   this.isCheccked=isChecked;
   }


   //write getters and setters for the given variables.
     }
```

in your Adapter.

when checkbox is clicked.

arraylist.setisChecked(true);
notifyDataSetChanged();